# How to make my object fire bullets one by one?

Tags: javascript, intervals

The main object keeps firing bullets and it looks like a lazer. I don't know how to make it fire one bullet at a press of a key. Do I need to use intervals?

```
var gameBullet=[];
var i=0;
//Starts game
function startGame() {
    myGameArea.start();
    myGamePiece= new component(20,20,"red",10,120);

}
//Creates canvas , events and how many times per sec should the object redraw
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 1);

        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('space',function(e){
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "space");
        })
    },
    clear: function(){
        this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
    }
}
//Bullet constructor
function bullet(width,height,color,x,y){
    this.gamearea=myGameArea;
    this.width=width;
    this.height=height;
    this.speedX=5;
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.update = function(){
        ctx=myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    this.newPos = function(){
        this.x+=this.speedX;
        this.hitBorder();
    }
    this.hitBorder = function() {
        var right = myGameArea.canvas.width - this.width;
        if (this.x > right) {
            this.x = right;
        }
    }
}
//Main Object constructor
function component(width,height,color,x,y){
    this.gamearea=myGameArea;
    var imageObj = new Image();
    this.width=width;
    this.height=height;
    this.speedX=0;
    this.speedY=0;
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.update= function(){
        ctx=myGameArea.context;

    /*        ctx.drawImage(imageObj,this.x,this.y, this.width, this.height);

          imageObj.src = 'stalin.png';
        */
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    this.newPos= function(){
        this.x+=this.speedX;
        this.y+=this.speedY;
        this.hitBorder();
    }
    this.hitBorder = function() {
        var down = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > down) {
            this.y = down;
        }
        if (this.y < 0) {
            this.y = 0;
        }
        var right = myGameArea.canvas.width - this.width;
        if (this.x > right) {
            this.x = right;
        }
        if (this.x < 0) {
           this.x = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I think here is the problem. I need to add something in the loop, but I don't know what.

```
//Updates game 
function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0;

    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.speedX = -1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.speedX = 1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.speedY = -1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.speedY = 1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[32])
    {
        gameBullet[i]=new bullet(5,5,"red",myGamePiece.x,myGamePiece.y);
        i=i+1;
    }

    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
    for( i=0;i<gameBullet.length;i+=1){
        gameBullet[i].newPos();
        gameBullet[i].update();
    }
}
startGame();
```

Comment: I found that the real problem is how to make the main object stop shooting while the spacebar key is being pressed.I need to make it shot one bullet even if the key is still pressed

Comment: Does keyboard repeat trigger the keydown event repeatedly? Also your keyup handler is triggering on keydown?

Answer (score 0):

you can use setinterval() in place of for loop

```
setinterval(yourcode,timespan);
```

Comment: you mean that i should put gameBullet[i].newPos(); gameBullet[i].update(); in place of "yourcode"?